# Compare %1 vs %* to see if multiple files dropped or not crashing cmd window? What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am attempting a basic comparison between passed arg, %1 and %*.

I am trying to determine if multiple files are dropped or not and this seems like it should be the easiest way?

I can echo them both fine, but when I try to compare them with IF NOT == the cmd window crashes..

```
ECHO %1
ECHO %*
IF NOT "%1" == "%*" ECHO NO
PAUSE
EXIT
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What about: ```If "%~1" == "" (Echo No args.) Else If "%~2" == "" (Echo One arg.) Else Echo More than one arg.```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was going to delete the question, but just in case someone else needs the answer...

It seems like its because of the quotes in the vars, so I used the below steps to remove them and then i am able proceed with the comparison..

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "PARAM=%1"
SET "PARAMS=%*"
SET "PARAM=%PARAM:"=%
SET "PARAMS=%PARAMS:"=%
IF "%PARAM%" == "%PARAMS%" (ECHO Single) ELSE (ECHO Multi)
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: A simpler way to see if multiple arguments were passed is to just check if `%2` has a value - `if "%~2"=="" echo only one argument given`

Comment: `%1` references the first argument string as passed to the batch file. If the first argument string is passed with surrounding `"` because of containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``, `%1` is replaced by the argument string with the double quotes. Now let us assume the batch file is called with `"C:\Temp\Development & Test(!) 100%.txt" "C:\Temp\  ;Another strange but valid file name.txt"`. If you run the batch file with first line changed to `@ECHO ON` from within a command line window with those two file names you will see what is the problem with your approach.

Comment: Why is it necessary if the batch file is called with just one or with multiple files? There can be used `if not "%~1" == "" for %%I in (%*) do echo Argument string: %%I` to process all files of which file name enclosed or not enclosed in `"` are passed to the batch file as argument string(s). There could (should) be above the for loop three more lines: `if "%~1" == "" goto OutputHelp` and `if "%~1" == "/?" goto OutputHelp` and `if "%~1" == "-?" goto OutputHelp` and remove `if not "%~1" == ""` from the `for` command line. PS: This solution makes it possible to pass a wildcard pattern too.

Comment: PPS: The execution of `EXIT` as last command of the batch file is always useless and just counterproductive. The batch file processing ends on `cmd.exe` reaches the end of the batch file with no more command which results in either exiting itself on `cmd.exe` being started with option `/C` as done on double clicking a batch file, or returning to the command prompt if a user first opens a command prompt (runs `cmd.exe` implicit with option `/K`) and runs the batch file with one or more arguments from within the command prompt window, or the batch file is called from another batch file.

Comment: @Mofi in this case it will work, as I am halting the script if a second param is detected. The point of what I am doing is to only allow one param, and 1% is being used because I am "Dragging and Dropping" something onto the cmd script. This prevents a group of files from being dropped. There are other sections that also check the validity of the file/filename/paths etc..

Comment: If the batch file should be run always with exactly one argument, I recommend using first `if "%~1" == "" echo ERROR: %~nx0 must be run with a file name as argument.& goto OutputHelp` and second `if not "%~2" == "" echo ERROR: %~nx0 can be run only with one file name as argument.& goto OutputHelp`. That are the two conditions for checking if the batch file is called without any argument or with more than one argument. Well, the second condition is not really enough if a user calls the batch file with `""` as second argument string which is an empty argument string.

Comment: A 100% check if there is more than one argument would be `set SecondArg=%2` and next `if defined SecondArg echo ERROR: %~nx0 can be run only with one file name as argument.& goto OutputHelp`. Those two command lines detect also an empty second argument string `""` which results in output of the error message and continue processing the batch file below the label `OutputHelp`.